# Meaning of "folksy side of the spectrum"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> He unlocked the door, stepped inside, hit the light. The decor ran to the ***folksy side of the spectrum***. Two badly done iconic Western scenes. A cowboy on a bucking bronco. Group of ranch hands huddled around a campfire.

Something like "Cowboy-ish shades of color"?

Source: Novel, Pines, Blake Crouch.

Answer (score 1):

We use the term 'spectrum' when something has a measurable range.

Your example is talking about 'decor', so the writer is suggesting that different tastes in decor could be placed on a 'range'.

"Folksy" refers to styles associated with folk music and culture, for example, the "hippy" style.

By saying "the folksy end of the spectrum" it is also suggesting that the style is an *extreme*. The ends of a spectrum are typically the most extreme - for example the unseen infrared and ultraviolet are off each end of the literal colour spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

This example does not specifically refer to the color of the room. The color spectrum here is a metaphor for the variety of aesthetic tastes.

Essentially what is written here is that the decor of the place is western-themed or consistent with unsophisticated rural people. The word "folksy" is a somewhat derogatory.